# postges запрос с декодированием

Tags: encoder

Добрый день подскажите как решить задачку.

Условие: Есть столбец data в base64, далее я его перевожу в HEX [encode(data, 'hex' )]
Если первый символ колонки data = 30, перевести всю строку в text
Если первый символ колонки data = 0f, оставить строку как есть
Вывести общий результат со всеми значениями

### Пример Результата:
Dataencode

00XXXXXXXXXX
0fXXXXXXXXXX